# How can I schedule a tweet that includes the coordinates for a specified location?

Tags: webapp-rec

I would like to take advantage of the location feature of Twitter which allows for specific coordinates to be included in your tweets.  I know that the location details for tweets are accessible from the RSS feed or Twitter API and I would like to use this in an integration project.  For my needs I would like to compose a few tweets to be posted on a schedule throughout the day.  Each scheduled tweets will need to include a unique location that I have pre-determined in advance.

I know that TweetDeck can actually do this however I am looking for an online web application that can do it.  This way it can be managed from any browser as opposed to TweetDeck, which would need to always be running on my desktop in order to send the scheduled tweets.

Does anyone have a suggestion or particular web application to recommend for meeting my needs?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Your first paragraph talks about using the API and your second talks about clients. The scheduled jobs need to be always running from somewhere. Once your desktop has some command line job function then you can automate it there. You would also need to know the place_id or lat and long for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there is a way you can schedule a Geo-location tweet via a website. Because if it were so, wouldn't you be defeating the whole purpose of the location based tweet? 
The best way to do this would be use the API directly and tweet. I don't think there are any existing solutions available out there to do this.

Comment: It wouldn't defeat the purpose for a "tweet-based scavenger hunt"!

Answer (score 0):

Not a website but there is an iPhone application called Tweet My Location ([iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tweet-my-location/id364087948?mt=8)). I got to know about that application via [this blog post](http://pepper.pk/detail-29-1). I understand that this forum is about Web Apps only. But, hope that helps.

Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using Foursquare would be a good idea in this situation.  It has no real location restriction on checking in, unless you want to earn foursquare points/badges (which I doubt you do).  Perhaps you could write a little script to call the Foursquare API?